# how to delete extry from export command in macos terminal (zsh)

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, alias

i put export command in zsh terminal

```
export
```

command in zsh terminal macos(Ventura).

which ends with

```
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
_CE_CONDA=''
_CE_M=''
__CFBundleIdentifier=com.apple.Terminal
alias=''
jpnb=jupyter-notebook
```

**how** **to delete** this " ***alias = ' '*** " and "***jpnb=jupyter-notebook***" and where is it stored?

it is not present in *.zshrc* or *.zprofile* profile.

i tried /proc/<pid>/environ but turns out its not in macos as id does not have a procfs.

Comment: That probably comes from a software that you installed, and Conda is always the most suspicious. You might also check what `/etc/zprofile`, `/etc/zshrc` and `/etc/launchd.conf` contain, but I don't think that any sane software would modify those files

Comment: These are indeed strange names for environment variables. As a first try, I would create a new subshell with `zsh -lx` and search the output for a possible mentioning of these variables (testing or setting). From the output, in which file it occurs. Did you check, whether they are maybe set in your `.zshenv` file?